# SQL query to find The attendance % of the group leader should be greater than the avg. attendance % of all members of HIS group

Tags: sql, join, average

In a class of 100 students, the Class Teacher wants to create groups of 10 with one group leader each. Students are allotted roll numbers (1,2,3…,100) based on the alphabetic ordering of their names. The CT goes with a simple approach and creates 10 groups basis their roll numbers. He also assigns one random person from the group to be the group leader -

G1 - 1 to 10 [Group leader - 6]

G2 - 11 to 20 [Group leader - 14]

G3 - 21 to 30 [Group leader - 25]

and so on…

Write a SQL query to classify the group leader elected by the CT as ‘eligible’/’not_eligible’ basis the eligibility criteria -

Eligibility criteria : The attendance % of the group leader should be greater than the avg. attendance % of all members of HIS group.

The data is stored in 2 tables as following -

[image]

Output required:

[image]

Comment: my approach so far
Q1. Query to make groups

 For the label groups

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN roll_number <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
         WHEN roll_number <= 20 THEN '11-20' 
         ELSE '21+'  --and so on
       END AS roll_number, 
       COUNT(*) AS n
FROM student_attendence
GROUP BY CASE 
           WHEN roll_number <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
           WHEN roll_number <= 20 THEN '11-20' 
           ELSE '21+'  --and so on
         END

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show what you tried & what relevant parts you can do. Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Comment: @rcs Please do not inline links inappropriately. See my comment above re using text whenever possible. Either replace a link to a table by code block formatted tabular text (which should simultaneously be code to create & initialize a table if the question should give a [mcve]) or, much better, comment to tell the poster to do it. PS This should downvoted & closed.

Answer (score 1):

"The CT goes with a simple approach and creates 10 groups basis their roll numbers."

That's where the problem is.  He should take the 10 persons with the highest attendance % and make those the group leaders.  Then your difficult problem of assessing "eligibility" has evaporated by definition.

But no doubt this is homework so here is the strategy :

1) Using joins, get a four-column table (roll_number student_attendance leader_roll_number leader_attendance)
2) Compute the AVG(student_attendance) per group (GROUP BY leader_roll_number)
3) Compare that to leader_attendance and using a CASE expression compute the value for your "eligible" column

I'm not going to spoonfeed you the SQL itself.

Comment: I figured as much, but thanks for the approach. I have the join part done. 
Its the AVG statement that I am unable to comprehend. Any help there would be appreciated!
thanks again

Comment: Since the group column is no pre-defined

Comment: SELECT AVG(p) FROM input GROUP BY g works as follows : it will first "partition" your input according to values of g - thus creating "groups" with identical g value - and then compute the average of p within each group - and the result table has one single row for each group

Answer (score -3):

If you need the query, here it is:

```
select distinct aa.leader_roll_number, (min_roll_no||'-'||max_roll_no) as grp , bb.student_attendance as leader_attendance, 
          case when avg(aa.student_attendance) over (partition by aa.leader_roll_number) < bb.student_attendance then 'eligible' else 'not eligibe' end as eligibility from
      (
      select roll_number, student_attendance, leader_roll_number, min(roll_number) over (partition by leader_roll_number) as min_roll_no, max(roll_number) over (partition by leader_roll_number) as max_roll_no from
           (
            select a.*, b.leader_roll_number from student_attendance a
                      join group_leader_mapping b on a.roll_number=b.roll_number
          )
      ) aa
      join          
      (        
      select distinct leader_roll_number, student_attendance from group_leader_mapping a
                join student_attendance b on a.leader_roll_number=b.roll_number
      ) bb  on  aa.leader_roll_number=bb. leader_roll_number      
      order by 1
```

Comment: Please look at the formatted version of your text before you post. Please edit this to format code in a code block. Please don't just dump code, explain why it answers the question. [answer]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Even ignoring the formatting, this isn't a very good answer, I'm afraid. It's much better to include information explaining what your answer does, and why it works, so that other people can learn from it, rather than just giving an answer. Also, notice that this was a homework question posted in 2016, the likelihood that the OP still cares is pretty low!